# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in JavaScript Memory game

Tags: javascript, memory

I have a problem with my JavaScript memory game, it's supposed to create some `<div/>` which will be responsible as a our memory game cards and the user can input before pressing the start button how much rows and columns he wants to have. But somehow I got an error saying: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**. This is the code responsible for creating the div table and not only:

```
function GameBoard(n,m) {
    this.n = n;
    this.m = m;

    score = 0;

    //n*m%2==0

    picBoard = new Array(n);
    last = -1;

    accepTab = new Array(n*m/2);
    for (var i=0; i<accepTab.length; i++){
        accepTab[i] = 0;
    }

    for (var i=0; i<picBoard.length; i++){
        picBoard[i] = new Array(m);
        for (var j=0; j<picBoard[i].length; j++){
            picBoard[i][j] = new Picture(accepTab);
        }
    }

    function getPicture(id) {
        console.log(picBoard);
        return picBoard[id[0]][id[1]].val
    }

    function show(obj){
        val = getPicture(getId(obj.id));
        $(obj).html(val);
        if(last==-1){
            last = val;
            lastId = getId(obj.id);
        } else {
            if(last==val){
                $('#score').html(++score);
            } else {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(obj).html("X");
                    $("#col"+lastId[0]+"_"+lastId[1]).html("X");
                }, 1000);

            }
            last=-1;
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        $("#board").append("<div class=row id=row"+i+"> ");
        for(var j=0; j<m; j++){
            $("#board #row"+i).append("<span class=col id=col"+i+"_"+j+">X");
            $("#col"+i+"_"+j).bind("click", function() {
                show(this);
            });

        }

    }

}
```

and the Console is saying the problem is with the line of function `getPicture` with return `picBoard[id[0]][id[1]].val`. And the function for Starting the game

```
var board;

function start(){
    var n = document.getElementById("rows").value;
    var m = document.getElementById("cols").value;
    board = new GameBoard(n,m);
    sec=0;
    $("#start").unbind("click");

}
```

Whenever I call the function `GameBoard` without `n` and `m` variables but instead of values like 3 and 4 everything is working fine, it's just the thing when I tried to give a user an option to choose how big he wants to have the table of memory cards.

Comment: If you do a little searching on that error message, you'll find that it's always because a variable is undefined that you're not expecting to be. The best way of figuring it out is to debug your code line by line, stepping through it until you get to the offending line.

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

n and m are strings, not numbers. So some of the operations you do will result in different things. So convert them to numbers

```
board = new GameBoard(+n,+m);
```